# Good Site Builder

Tags: templates, content-management-system, builder

I am currently working on a website and i kinda need something like a cms/site builder to be integrated int the site, but not very complicated. 
for example let's say i have a few templates and the users can modify them as they please(add a picture, some text, etc)

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey prsegiu, this isn't really the place to ask questions like this. This is a site for programming questions and answers. Please read the SO faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Please ask this at superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

look at N2 if you are working in .Net  http://n2cms.com/

Answer (score 0):

try joomla, drupal, or wordpress. There are also some basic wiki sites that are easy to setup and use like TWiki.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things very basic then [SnippetMaster](http://www.snippetmaster.com) is an option. Your users can edit odd bits of text and even add pictures. It works best for sites with only a few pages to update. For a large site you may want to look at something more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) (PHP) or [Windows SharePoint Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/default.aspx) (.NET), but it depends what kind of thing you are really after...

Also, you could use something like [VS Web Developer 2008 Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) which'll create a basic template for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a site these days with [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/). Actually I recommend this even if you have more complicated stuff. There are a lot of plugins and themes and over all support. If you want something simple you can have it in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awesome link that I just happened to have someone send me yesterday:
[Top 10 free content management systems for web site designers](http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwebdesignledger.com%2Ftools%2F10-best-content-management-systems-for-designers&h=0161dcde98b213801d6376ed28cd4a75)